# I get a syntax error when I try to execute a query

Tags: database

Each time I run the following code, I get an error.

```
$result = db_query(“SELECT nid FROM 'msg'”);
foreach ($result as $record) {
  // Do something with each $record
}
```

The error is the following one:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
$result = db_query("SELECT id FROM {mg}");
```

It doesn't look like you should get parse error unless you really use `“”` and not `""`

Comment: It now works great thanks GoogleTorp :) "" was wrong copy and paste error and also {} needed

Answer (score 1):

I copied the following code in a text file named "test.php."

```
<?php
  $result = db_query(“SELECT nid FROM 'node'”);
  foreach ($result as $record) {
   dsm($record->nid);
  }
```

When I executed "php -l test.php," I got the following error message:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in test.php on line 2

I then changed the code to the following one, and "php -l test.php" didn't report any syntax error.

```
<?php
  $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM 'node'");
  foreach ($result as $record) {
   dsm($record->nid);
  }
```

The problem is then the fact you are using *“* as string delimiter.

The query you are using is not correct in Drupal, where the table name is surrounded with curly brackets, not string delimiters.

The code should be written as the following one:

```
<?php
  $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node}");
  foreach ($result as $record) {
   dsm($record->nid);
  }
```

The database API functions will replace the curly brackets with the string set as table prefix in settings.php.